# Arbitrary Constant in Electric Potential

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, conventions

Consider an electric potential that is the result of a superposition of two electric potentials:

$$\Phi = -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\left[\int_{O}^bE_1 \cdot dr+\int_O^bE_2 \cdot dr\right].$$

If we set the potential at O arbitrarily to a constant K, wouldn't we end up with an electric potential of:

$$V_1 +V_2 +2K.$$

Or,

$$\Phi = V + 2K$$

Which is different from the expected $\Phi = V + K$.

I must be doing something wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: set $b=O$. You tried to specify that the potential there should be $K$, but your procedure gives something different, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified extremities in your integral, you computed an integral, not a primitive, so there's no free constant remaining.

Going back to basic notations, this is an integral:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$$
with $F$ any primitive of $f$. You can see that adding any constant to $F$ doesn't change the result since it's a difference. On the other hand, this is a primitive:
$$\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+\text{any constant}$$

Going back to your calculation, let $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be the potentials related to, respectively, $\vec{E}_1$ and $\vec{E}_2$:
$$\vec{E}_1=-\vec{\nabla}\phi_1\qquad\vec{E}_2=-\vec{\nabla}\phi_2$$
Using, for any gradient:
$$dV=\vec{\nabla}V.d\vec{r}$$
your calculation becomes:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^b\vec{E}_1.d\vec{r}+\int_0^b\vec{E}_2.d\vec{r}
&=-\int_0^bd\phi_1-\int_0^b\phi_2\\
&=\phi_1(0)-\phi_1(b)+\phi_2(0)-\phi_2(b)\\
&=\phi(0)-\phi(b)
\end{aligned}$$
with $\phi=\phi_1+\phi_2$. You can add any constant to total potential $\phi$, but due to the difference, the result doesn't change. What you just computed is a voltage, not a potential: a voltage is a difference of potential.

If you decide that $\phi(0)=0$, then the potential happens to be numerically equals to the voltage.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. Thank you! My confusion was in not fully processing that it is the function $\Phi$ itself that one can an arbitrary constant to. This is different from setting a point in space to take on an arbitrary potential value. Such that $\Phi(b)=\Phi_1+K$, $\Phi(O) = 0 + K$, etc.

Comment: Conceptually, changing the arbitrary constant amounts to adding or subtracting the constant from the potential everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \Delta V =  -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_{O}^bE \cdot dr$

You have missed the point that when you are integrating the right-hand side the numerical value only depends on the electric field and position not any choice of the zero of potential.

I have shown this diagrammatically below.

[image]

In terms of numbers suppose $ -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_{O}^bE_1 \cdot dr= 6$ and $-\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_O^bE_2 \cdot dr = 8$

then $-\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}[\int_{O}^bE_1 \cdot dr+\int_O^bE_2 \cdot dr]= -\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_{O}^bE_1 \cdot dr-\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\int_O^bE_2 \cdot dr=6+8 = 14$

In general $V = V_1+V_2-K$ and using the numerical example $14+K = (6+K) + (8+K) - K$